# Static assets not being served through Cloudflare CDN

Tags: cdn, cloudflare, gtmetrix

So I am new to gatsbyjs and CDN's. My website is hosted on a2hosting and is going through Cloudflare, but when run a test on GTmetrix it says these files aren't going through the CDN, what am I doing wrong?[image]

Comment: Without more context, check the proxy status for that DNS record inside your Cloudflare console. You should see an orange cloud if Cloudflare is proxying that content.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you only set the NS-Record with CloudFlare, but your A-Record is still pointing to your hosting provider directly. You need to change that record to work with Cloudflare.
Check your records:
https://bhnd.io/pixelfriendly.co.za/
Check the Cloudflare documentation:
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205195708-Changing-your-domain-nameservers-to-Cloudflare
If that doesn't help, I would recommend sending Cloudflare a support request, they probably have more insights and can tell you what's wrong.